# Unity database, php code getting null data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

In a php code I have get names and highscores :

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['komut']) && $_REQUEST['veriCekme']!="") {
$almak=$vt->query ("select * from topdowngame"); //my database name
if ($almak -> rowCount()) {
    foreach ($almak as $row) {
        echo $row['name'].";";
        echo $row['highscore'].";";
    }
}
```

}

I getting null in unity console

UnityScript :

```
IEnumerator kayit_cek ()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField ("komut", "veriCekme");
    string url = "http://localhost/database.php";
    WWW w = new WWW(url, form);
    yield return w;
    gelenVeriler = w.text.Split(';');
    Debug.Log(w.text);
}
```

Sorry for my bad English.

[image: unity console picture]

Answer (score 0):

The [`AddField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.AddField.html) method takes a name and value, and in your code you are creating a single field with a name of `komut` and a value of `veriCekme`:

```
form.AddField ("komut", "veriCekme");
```

On the PHP-side of things, you are looking for two form fields:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['komut']) && $_REQUEST['veriCekme']!="")
```

I don't know your language or what these words mean, but if you are intending to send a single field and wanted a special value you would do it like this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['komut']) && $_REQUEST['komut']==="veriCekme")
```